# My ember APP adds unexpected record after displaying

Tags: javascript, api, express, ember.js, ember-cli

when I click in post title ('Test post') [here](http://pikturo.pl/blog) and when I return to post's list I have unexpected empty record. This is a strange behaviour. I have simple construction:

Ember model (post.js):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  intro: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Ember routes:

```
this.route('posts', {path: 'blog'}, function() {
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_slug'});
  });
```

index.js - for list

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var posts = this.store.findAll('post');
    return posts;
  }
});
```

post.js - for single post

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_slug);
    }
});
```

Ember serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id',
  serializeId: function(id) {
        return id.toString();
  },
  extractCreateRecord: function() {
    // do nothing
  }
});
```

and I use RESTAdapter.

Express API:

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    Posts.find(function(err, response) {
        posts = response;
        res.json({posts: posts});
    });
});

app.get('/api/posts/:url', function(req, res) {
    Posts.findOne({slug:req.params.url},function(err, response){
        post = response;
    res.json({post: post});
    });
});
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your serializer, the `primaryKey` should be `product_slug` instead of `_id`. Ember needs to be told that it should treat the slug as the unique identifier. Your exact problem is mentioned in the blog post below...

http://fullstackstanley.com/read/handling-slug-urls-in-ember-and-phoenix

If you look in the Ember inspector (also mentioned in the blog post) you'll see you have one record with ID `5672f9551615cf0b07e1c3cf` and one with `test-post`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your great response Keith. You are right. My problem has been solved. Many, many thanks.